# ui-sref active is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

ui-sref-active is not working for following scenario:

```
<li ui-sref=".flavors({trigger:value })"    ui-sref-active="currentState">Flavors</li>
```

I have used `$state` for knowing state name and the state name is showing **azure.flavors**.

However the `currentState` class is not added to the link.

```
  <li>{{$state.current.name}}</li>
```

this is my state in app.js

```
.state('azure.flavors', {

    url:'/azureFlavors?trigger',
    templateUrl :'partials/azure/azureFlavorsList.html',
    controller : 'azureFlavorsListCtrl'

})
```

if you  have any doubt on my question please ask me i want sol.
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1431

Comment: Is there any anchor tag used?

Comment: yes squiroid i have checked ii did't get sol

Comment: @reena no i didn't use any anchor tag

Comment: actually i want reload azure.flavors when i click on flavors list which doesn't take any param for reload that child state only i have added dummy trigger to reload that state finally the state is reloading but the state is not activated

Comment: Not entirely sure but try setting the sref to `azure.flavors`?

Comment: As suggested above have u tried this:  <li ui-sref="azure.flavors({trigger:value }) ui-sref-active="currentState">Flavours
      </li>

Comment: I think the only problem is in this ({trigger:value })

Comment: @Reena I tried the snippet which you gave but that is also not working

Comment: @Reena Actually i want reload only child state that is .flavors for that purpose i have added dummy trigger param for reload that state (note: i am changon the trigger value every time)

Comment: <li ui-sref=".volumes" ui-sref-active="currentState">Volumes</li>
fot this snippet currentState is working
but for flavors its not working

Comment: oh then how can we pass param to state ?
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Project/home.html#/azure/azureFlavors?trigger=3
I am getting this url in my browser

Comment: var params = angular.extend({}, $state.params, { trigger: $state.params.trigger ? undefined : 'x' });
  $state.transitionTo($state.current, params, { });

I tried like this also but same problem ui-sref active is not working

Comment: Try this once  "url:'/azureFlavors/:trigger' ".

Comment: it is reloading nicely but the ui-sref-active is not working

Answer (score 0):

Ui-sref directive shoud be used with `a` tag, not `li`.

Comment: <li ui-sref=".volumes" ui-sref-active="currentState">Volumes</li>
working nice for above sniipet
but it is not working for below snippet

   <li  ui-sref=".flavors({trigger:value}) " ui-sref-active="currentState"> Flavors</li>